# JS (yii) открыть страницу/div?

Tags: javascript, yii

Есть боковое меню с картой сайта. Есть основной блок контента. Все сделано на yii. Основной блок контента - по сути фрейм (iframe), куда загружается та или иная страница. Есть ли какая функция у js\yii, чтобы при клике на ссылке обновлялся див\фрейм, а карта не менялась?

--
появилась шальная мысль - делаем пункты карты ajaxlink.

соответственно в контроллер передаем id\url.

в ajaxoption выставляем update => content. 
при этом в контролере должен отработать скрипт window.location.href(url).

ну это в порядке бреда.

Comment: Использование фреймов - это устаревшая техника, которая нарушает некоторые принципы веба (та же банальная проблема с адресной строкой). В 2015 не стоит строить сайты на фреймах.

Comment: ну как тогда решить эту задачу?